# How to change Text Editor font colour in Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

In previous versions of Eclipse it was possible to change the font colour of the general Text Editor in the dialogue  *General* > *Editors* > *Text Editors*. In Eclipse Neon this has no effect:

[image]

How can this be made with this latest version?